# how to monitor any changes to any file by using vi command

Tags: vi

Im looking for a tools (script) for monitoring my systems for any changes on any files by using vi command.
 For example: one dba open alert.log with vi and modify it and save.. i need to trace these changes.
 Is it possible?  
 Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea it's possible just not with vi... I mean check inotify tools ; with those you can monitor for file changes, moving , deleting , creation it wont tell you with which tool action was made but it will alert that something had happened.

if you want to track only actions with vi I suggest you make a wrapper for vi that will alert of any usage/invocation say make sum of file before edit; after edit; if it was changed raise alert.